# For each date, print event three time

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to print for each elements from the list date  three elements from the event list

```
    @Test
    public void Container() throws InterruptedException {

        List<WebElement> date = driver.findElements(
            By.cssSelector("td.first.member-area"));
        List<WebElement> event = driver.findElements(
            By.cssSelector("span.selection-link.normal"));

        System.out.println(date.size());
        System.out.println(" =============== Offer ================= ");

        for (int j = 0; j < date.size(); j++) {
            System.out.println(date.get(j).getText() + "\t - " + event.get(j).getText() ) ;
        }    
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use nested loops.

```
for (int j = 0; j < date.size(); j++) {
    System.out.println(date.get(j).getText());
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        System.out.println(event.get(i).getText());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!